# Asp.Net Core - Start background task and ensure only one are running

Tags: asp.net-core, background-process

I would like to start a long running task from an API controller and return 200 when the task is started.

I want only one task running and if another request are coming in, the controller should check if there is already a task running.
It the task is running just forget the request. If not start a new task.

Was thinking of using this code [fire and forget in ASP.NET Core with dependency alive](https://anduin.aiursoft.com/post/2020/10/14/fire-and-forget-in-aspnet-core-with-dependency-alive) to start the task. Then I need some thread safe place to store a IsRunning variable.

Comment: Can you use Session?

Comment: azure function, azure webjob, message queue, etc....

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked [Hangfire](https://www.hangfire.io/)
?

In can be run in cluster mode and also you can query to check if a specific task in running.